# Prime Number Calculation. Can someone explain the code?

Tags: java

Please can someone explain how this works? The lines of code I dont understand are marked in the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    class PrimeCheck
    {
      public static void main(String args[])
      {     
        boolean isPrime=true;

        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter any number:");
        int num=scan.nextInt();
            scan.close();
        for(int i=2;i<num;i++)
        {           
           if(num%i==0)  // I don't understand this part!
           {
              isPrime=false; // I don't understand this part!
              break;
           }
        }
        if(isPrime)
           System.out.println(num + " is a Prime Number");
        else
           System.out.println(num + " is not a Prime Number");
       }
    }
```

Comment: Try to debug the code or add `System.out.println("number="+i);` into for loop.

Comment: `isPrime=false;` is pretty self explanatory. Assign false to variable isPrime. So isPrime is now false.

Comment: It is not neccessary to use num in the loop, working up to num/2 is sufficient, because you cannot divide by something larger than half an expect a whole result: i.e. 1000/501 .... 1000/999 are all useless calxulations.

Comment: Mention what exactly you don't understand.. eg.. why is this written / what it does etc.. A debugging will give you clear idea as it transforms different variables

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the code below. This should show you how the % (modulo) operator works.
In short, it divides the argument by 2 and tells you the **remaining part**.

```
a = 2
isEven = (a % 2) == 0;
```

2 divided by 2 is 1 and gives 0 rest. Since 0 == 0, the number is **even!**

```
a = 5
isEven = (a % 2) == 0;
```

5 divided by 2 is 2 and has 1 rest. 1 is not equal to 0, so the number is **not even.**

Answer (score 0):

Please check the explaination of % operator from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_programming/computer_programming_operators.htm

In short summary the program is dividing the input number by all the numbers from 2 to the number - 1 and if it is divisible by that number it is setting isPrime to false(because definition of prime numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly what modulus operator does is, it finds the remainder.

for ex -> 5%2 = 1 (remainder)

And the number is prime if it is only divisible by 1 and itself(that number).

for ex - 2,3,5,7 ..... AS these are divisible by only 1 and themselves.

Here in your program, as 1 can be divisible by all numbers so i = 2 is taken.
and for prime number check, Here we are checking whether this number is divisible by any other number or NOT. If it is divisible by any other number then "isPrime" flag becomes "false" and as break is there control comes out of loop.

Then checking if  "isPrime" true then its a "prime number"
OTHERWISE "Not PRIME".